# Simulink - Combining Variable Types

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am new to Simulink, and am trying to model a chilled water plant.
Trying to model the pressure, flow and temperature at the same time, I see this constraint on the type of variables.

Trying to utilize the provided library, I see that each component can only model a given variable type. However, from my limited knowledge on physics or chem, I believe at least pressure and temperature are related.

Is there a way generate a model that combines the two (or any multiple) variable types? Any reference of tutorial would be appreciative.

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: @Umar Had this solved by using the 'Thermal Liquid' library. Thanks.